# PowerApps - ¿How to apply 4 filter in a gallery?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven

```
SortByColumns(
Search(
    Filter(
        Switch(
            true;
            Dropdown_Equipo_Estado_2.SelectedText.Value <> "Todos";
            Filter( 
                TRASLADO_EQUIPO; 
                ( LOCALIZACION_ORIGEN_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID || 
                LOCALIZACION_DESTINO_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID)  &&
                ESTADO = Dropdown_Equipo_Estado_2.SelectedText.Value
                );
            Dropdown_Equipo_Estado_2.SelectedText.Value = "Todos"; //Funciona
            Filter( 
                TRASLADO_EQUIPO; 
                ( LOCALIZACION_ORIGEN_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID || 
                LOCALIZACION_DESTINO_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID)
                ); 
            Filter(
                TRASLADO_EQUIPO;
                ( LOCALIZACION_ORIGEN_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID || 
                LOCALIZACION_DESTINO_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID)
                )
            );
            FECHA_CREACION >= DatePicker1_1.SelectedDate
        );
     TextInput6.Text; "ID"); 
     "ID";
     Ascending)
```

This code pretends to filter a gallery with dropdowns according to the status of the element, the location and the date from which the element is displayed; however when I want to add a function to filter by searching the sharepoint ID code of the list, it does not allow me to filter it, there is an error; if I remove the search function to filter by the ID, the code executes correctly the location, status and date filters; the main problem is to integrate the search filter.

I attach the functional code without the search function, so you can compare what I have been doing.

```
SortByColumns(
Filter(
Switch(
    true;
    Dropdown_Equipo_Estado_2.SelectedText.Value <> "Todos";
    Filter( 
        TRASLADO_EQUIPO; 
        ( LOCALIZACION_ORIGEN_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID || 
        LOCALIZACION_DESTINO_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID)  &&
        ESTADO = Dropdown_Equipo_Estado_2.SelectedText.Value);
    Dropdown_Equipo_Estado_2.SelectedText.Value = "Todos"; //Funciona
    Filter( 
        TRASLADO_EQUIPO; 
        ( LOCALIZACION_ORIGEN_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID || 
        LOCALIZACION_DESTINO_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID));
        
    Filter(
        TRASLADO_EQUIPO;
        ( LOCALIZACION_ORIGEN_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID || 
        LOCALIZACION_DESTINO_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID)));
    
        FECHA_CREACION >= DatePicker1_1.SelectedDate

); "ID";Ascending)
```

[This is what the application looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJXDc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution

```
SortByColumns(
Search(
    Filter(
        Switch(
            true;
            Dropdown_Equipo_Estado_2.SelectedText.Value <> "Todos";
            Filter( 
                TRASLADO_EQUIPO; 
                ( LOCALIZACION_ORIGEN_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID || 
                LOCALIZACION_DESTINO_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID)  &&
                ESTADO = Dropdown_Equipo_Estado_2.SelectedText.Value
                );
            Dropdown_Equipo_Estado_2.SelectedText.Value = "Todos"; //Funciona
            Filter( 
                TRASLADO_EQUIPO; 
                ( LOCALIZACION_ORIGEN_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID || 
                LOCALIZACION_DESTINO_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID)
                ); 
            Filter(
                TRASLADO_EQUIPO;
                ( LOCALIZACION_ORIGEN_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID || 
                LOCALIZACION_DESTINO_ID = Dropdown_Equipo_Localizacion_2.Selected.ID)
                )
            );
            FECHA_CREACION >= DatePicker1_1.SelectedDate
        );
    TextInput6.Text;
    "{Identifier}"
);
"ID";
Descending)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helped you.

Comment: Many Thanks Tyler2P; i´m a beginner in the use of stackoverflow... i´ll take your recommendation